# How do specializations work?

Tags: spells, dresden-files

In Dresden Files, when constructing spells, how do I know if I get to have specializations, how many I get, and to what do they apply?

Comment: You seem to have three questions here thus you should ask three separate questions. With a little more fleshing out, those would be good questions.

Comment: Yes, please reduce this to just one question and post the other two as two more question posts. This can be reopened once it's just one question. Thanks!

Comment: Oy.  Well, answer updated then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends which part of the rules you mean.

- **Specialization** is a key word used in the wizard-level fully-powered Evocation and Thaumaturgy powers, representing your refined areas of talent.  It gives a +1 bonus to power *or* control for one area of spellcasting only.  The Refinement power can grant more of these.  You would need to choose how these apply as you choose the powers. (see Spellcraft powers on YS-p.179)  None of these powers are expected on a starting character, unless your GM is intentionally starting off with overpowered refresh rates.
- You get a handful of **focus item** crafting slots when you pick up even beginner spellcrafting powers, to create things like blasting rods and the like.  These are another +1 bonus to power or control in a specific area, that you would designate as you set up your character, same as specialization, only as an item it can be lost/stolen/mishandled.  (the number of slots is listed under the Power you get; the rules for Crafting are at YS-p.278)  For starting characters, who may only have one area of magic to access anyway, this is probably what to start looking at.
- Finally, you can designate specific evocation spells as **rote spells**, as many as you have skill in Lore (see YS-p.257).  This is less a bonus and more a convenience; rote spells get an automatic 0 roll for the Discipline check to control them, so no chance of failure.  If the spell needs to be aimed, the Discipline roll would count only for aiming and not for the control.

Your character building in general should be to figure out Aspects and Concept first, then choose Powers and Skills to suit (that part includes figuring out what would apply from the above list and making those choices as well), and then build some spells taking it all into account.  In that order, it should be clearer what applies where.

I'll just put this away... <strike>You should have at least some spells sketched out and ready to go when you play.</strike>

The main reason to do so would be time.  The character you build and the powers you take will have several restrictions built in, but spellcasting is one of the most versatile parts of the game.  It would be poor manners to ask the table to wait while you sort out what you'd like to do, every time you reach for magic.  At the same time, understand that magic is flexible - if you think of something new and cool at the table, don't be afraid to suggest it and ask for help in figuring out how it would work.

How you construct your spells, unfortunately, is going to depend on the powers you take.  Practicioners are required to take Channeling (evocation/quick-spells) or Ritual (thaumaturgy/broad-spells) or both, each of which are restricted to your Focus.  So you need to figure out what kind of spell it would be for the effect you want first.

The complete rules for Spellcasting and putting together spells run through the entire Chapter 13 on Your Story, that'd be too much to completely cover here.  In real brief, you need to figure out how much power the spell should have - sourced from a Conviction roll for evocation and your Lore and other role-play for thaumaturgy.  For evocation you need to further define the effect as an attack, block, maneuver, or counterspell.  For thaumaturgy you need to define a link your spell will use to find its target.

Once you have the specifics set up, it just a matter of when to use it and succeeding the rolls for gathering energy (power) and controlling it (aim).

When in doubt, check with your GM, or there's a great bit of advice in the rules - figure out what you'd like to do first, then find the right rule to fit it.